# zend 1 view helper functions use in another view helper class

Tags: php, zend-framework, helper

i have two helper classes

link are :

C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\application\views\helpers\comman.php

C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\application\views\helpers\RefineUrl.php

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Refinestr
{
    public function Refinestr($str, $options = array()){
     ..............
     .............
     return $str;
    }


}
```

second is

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Comman
{
    public function Comman(){
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPageContent($pageId){
        //  return $pageId;
        $mapper  = new Application_Model_StaticpageMapper();
        $selectedFields=array('desc');
        $tblName=array($mapper->getDbTable()->_name);
        $whr= "`id`=$pageId";
        $content=$mapper->fetchSelectedFields($tblName,$selectedFields,$whr);

        $des=$content[0]['desc'];
// here i want to use function Refinestr() of another helper class how i use this
$des=$this->Refinestr($des); 
// not working , searching this function inside comman class

    } }
```

How to use one helper class function in another helper class function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below trick for your case.

While calling `getPageContent()` helper from your `view` file pass the `view object` in helper as a `param` (like `$pageId`) and use that `view object` to call another helper in helper definition.

`View` file:

```
<?php echo $this->getPageContent($pageId, $this); ?>
```

Helper File:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_GetPageContent {
    public function getPageContent($pageId, $viewObj) {
        // return $pageId;
        $mapper = new Application_Model_StaticpageMapper ();
        $selectedFields = array ('desc' 
        );
        $tblName = array ($mapper->getDbTable ()->_name 
        );
        $whr = "`id`=$pageId";
        $content = $mapper->fetchSelectedFields ( $tblName, $selectedFields, $whr );

        $des = $content [0] ['desc'];
        // here i want to use function Refinestr() of another helper class how i
        // use this
        $des = $viewObj->Refinestr($des); //use view object to call another helper
    }
}
```

Another helper will remain as it is.

One more solution to this problem could be, set view object in `Zend Registry` at the time of bootstrapping and use that `registry variable` in helper file to call another helper.

In `Bootstrap` File:

```
protected function _initConfig() {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $this->_view = $this->getResource('view');
    Zend_Registry::set('viewObj', $this->_view);
}
```

`Helper` File:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_GetPageContent {
        public function getPageContent($pageId) {
            // return $pageId;
            $mapper = new Application_Model_StaticpageMapper ();
            $selectedFields = array ('desc');
            $tblName = array ($mapper->getDbTable ()->_name);
            $whr = "`id`=$pageId";
            $content = $mapper->fetchSelectedFields ( $tblName, $selectedFields, $whr );

            $des = $content [0] ['desc'];
            // here i want to use function Refinestr() of another helper class how i
            // use this
            $viewObj = Zend_Registry::get('viewObj');
            $des = $viewObj->Refinestr($des); //use view object to call another helper
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following:

Inside helper1

```
$this->helper1()->view->helper2();
```

In case helper1 is taking some arguments, I modify it to take no arguments and just return. Try it out, may work.